# Combining QueryParameters in ElasticSearch Java APi

Tags: elasticsearch

I have json object i want to search through it looks like this
I currently am able to do a range of price search but i want to add search by city , which is a property of departure object so i decided to do a nested query but i get error

My ES logs shows

```
e_synonyms_phrase_query":true,"boost":1.0}}}],"adjust_pure_negative":true,"boost":1.0}},"path":"departure","ignore_unmapped":false,"score_mode":"avg","boost":1.0}}],"adjust_pure_negative":true,"boost":1.0}}}}] lastShard [true]
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [AoBfpnE][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryShardException: failed to create query: {
  "bool" : {
    "filter" : [
      {
        "range" : {
          "price" : {
            "from" : 1300,
            "to" : 5000,
            "include_lower" : true,
            "include_upper" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "nested" : {
          "query" : {
            "bool" : {
              "must" : [
                {
                  "match" : {
                    "departure.city" : {
                      "query" : "minsk",
                      "operator" : "OR",
                      "prefix_length" : 0,
                      "max_expansions" : 50,
                      "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
                      "lenient" : false,
                      "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
                      "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
                      "boost" : 1.0
                    }
                  }
                }
              ],
              "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
              "boost" : 1.0
            }
          },
          "path" : "departure",
          "ignore_unmapped" : false,
          "score_mode" : "avg",
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryShardContext.toQuery(QueryShardContext.java:320) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryShardContext.toQuery(QueryShardContext.java:303) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct query looks like this:

```
    QueryBuilder range = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("price")
            .from(minPrice)
            .to(maxPrice)
            .includeLower(true)
            .includeUpper(true);

    QueryBuilder city = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("departure.city", city);

    QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .filter(range)
            .filter(city);

    ...

    searchSourceBuilder.query(query);
```

Comment: thanks actually it works for parameters such as nights, people but not for city , I think because city belongs to an object , so when i run your code it retruns empty but if i change departure.city to nights and give it value it returns data

Comment: If `departure` is not of type `nested` but `object` it should work. What's the mapping of the `departure` field?

Comment: so  the whole data is mapped to a Tour class while departure is a object that Tour is composed off

Comment: what do you get when running `GET your_index` ?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: [nested] nested object under path [departure] is not of nested type

Comment: i get this when i run departure.city

Comment: I'd like to see your mapping. Please run `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index` and share your result, please

Comment: have you seen it

Comment: yes, so `departure` is not `nested`, so you don't need any nested query, mine should work

Comment: You haven't taken my query, you still have your `nestedQuery`, you need to remove it and take only what I have provided in my answer

Comment: yes i just did it , your answer is right , the issue what the value i entered as city was in english while in json data was given in another language

Comment: can you give me an example of a json data that is nested so when i see it i will know i should use nested query

Comment: See here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html